# Test a method that is called from rx

Tags: android, mvvm, mockito, retrofit, rx-java

I created a method that receives some data from `web-service`, I am using `retrofit`, `rx`, and I am using `juint` and `mockito` to tests my code. I can test this method very well, but in `onCompleted` method of `rx`, I am calling another method(**saveToDatabase**)

How can I separate this dependency? I don't want to call this method in my test, please see my code below:

```
subscription = githubService.publicRepositories(username)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(application.defaultSubscribeScheduler())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Repository>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted()
                    {

                        progressVisibility.set(View.INVISIBLE);
                        if (!repositories.isEmpty())
                        {
                            recyclerViewVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            infoMessage.set(context.getString(R.string.text_empty_repos));
                            infoMessageVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        //THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT BE CALLED IN MY TEST, I WANT TO VERIFY IT
                        saveToDatabase(MainViewModel.this.repositories);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading GitHub repos ", error);
                        progressVisibility.set(View.INVISIBLE);
                        if (isHttp404(error))
                        {
                            infoMessage.set(context.getString(R.string.error_username_not_found));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            infoMessage.set(context.getString(R.string.error_loading_repos));
                        }
                        infoMessageVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Repository> repositories)
                    {
                        MainViewModel.this.repositories = repositories;
                    }
                });
```

and it is my test:

```
String username = "usernameWithRepos";
        TextView textView = new TextView(application);
        textView.setText(username);
        List<Repository> mockRepos = MockModelFabric.newListOfRepositories(10);
        doReturn(rx.Observable.just(mockRepos)).when(githubService).publicRepositories(username);

        mainViewModel.onSearchAction(textView, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH, null);
        verify(dataListener).onRepositoriesChanged(mockRepos);
        assertEquals(mainViewModel.infoMessageVisibility.get(), View.INVISIBLE);
        assertEquals(mainViewModel.progressVisibility.get(), View.INVISIBLE);
        assertEquals(mainViewModel.recyclerViewVisibility.get(), View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** not to call this method in the test. Instead, add to your class *database dependency* and mock it. E.g.:

```
//in your class
DataBaseClass databaseClass = new ...
...
dataBaseClass.save(...);

//in your test
@Mock DataBaseClass databaseClass;
```